# ε is preassigned, choosen or given in the (ε, δ)-definition of limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers, quantifiers

Most of the textbooks as I have ever seen don't point out ε to be **preassigned**, **choosen** or  **given**  in the (ε, δ)-definition of limit, but [some does](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Smfr8FAotiEC&lpg=SL4-PA24&ots=t5ssFgdlMe&dq=limit%20definition%20preassigned&hl=zh-CN&pg=SL4-PA24#v=onepage&q=pre-assigned&f=false), that is, the definition of limit becomes : For every **preassigned**, **choosen** or  **given** real  ε > 0, there exists a real δ > 0 such that for all real x, 0 < | x − a | < δ implies | f(x) − L | < ε.

So is there a need to obviously emphasize that ε is **preassigned**, **choosen** or  **given**  in the (ε, δ)-definition of limit?

Comment: I don't understand what "pc or g" adds to the sentence. "For every A, there is a B" is quite clear already - it means that, for every A, there is a B.

Comment: It isn't really "chosen" or "given." Although you can phrase it, I suppose, as "If you give me an $\epsilon>0$, I can find a $\delta>0$ such that..." Mathematicians simply say "for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that..." This doesn't imply there is a method of finding $\delta,$ necessarily, just that it is out there.  It might be useful for teaching purposes to get students to think of the $\epsilon$ as something given, but they need to realize that they need to know how to handle any $\epsilon.$

Comment: It means taken randomly in $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: They basically mean the same thing. For example, if John "gives" you $\epsilon = 0.0001$ and Emily "gives" you $\epsilon = 0.0012019391$, both $\epsilon$'s will work. To me that's what "given" means.

Comment: $\epsilon$ doesn't "work" or "not work,"  @MathematicsStudent1122 What you need to know is that you can find a $\delta$ in these and *any* other $\epsilon.$

Comment: There is no need to make this emphasis, because in all mathematical writing, the quantifier "for all" has one meaning, and the quantifier "there exists" has one meaning. If you start looking at other definitions, theorems, or proofs in your calculus book or in other mathematical books, you will see these quantifiers **everywhere**, and wherever you see them they have their standard meanings.

Comment: @LeeMosher what is the " one meaning"? what is the "standard meanings"?

Comment: You should probably get a good book on the foundations of mathematics, but here's a very brief overview. Suppose I have a mathematical sentence with a variable $\epsilon$, let's denote that sentence $P(\epsilon)$. The statement "for all $\epsilon>0, P(\epsilon)$" means that $P(.01)$ is true and $P(.0001)$ is true and $P(.00000000001)$ is true and $P(.0000000000409850473265)$ is true, and in fact no matter what positive number I subsitute for $\epsilon$, $P(\epsilon)$ is true.

Comment: Now suppose I have a mathematical sentence with a variable $\delta$, let's denote that sentence $Q(\delta)$. The statement "there exists $\delta > 0, Q(\delta)$" means that amongst all the many possible choice of a postive number $\delta$, somewhere there is one value of $\delta$ which makes $Q(\delta)$ true; it might not be $\delta = .1$, so I have no guarantee that $Q(.1)$ is true; it might not be $\delta = .0000004987$, so I have no guarnatee that $Q(.0000004987)$ is true; but there is *some* positive value of $\delta$ which makes $Q(\delta)$ true.

Comment: Now let's put it together and suppose I have a statement $R(\epsilon,\delta)$ which has two variables in it. The statement "there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$, $R(\epsilon,\delta)$" means that no matter what positive number I substitute for $\epsilon$, somewhere there is one value of $\delta$ which makes $R(\epsilon,\delta)$ true. The $\delta$ you get will generally depend on which $\epsilon$ you substituted.

Comment: There is no need. This sort of usage typically appear in a lengthy argument where multiple variables can/may change. You emphasis a variable, say $\epsilon$, is chosen/preassigned to inform the reader for (and only for) the next few paragraphs of the argument, the $\epsilon$ should be treated as if it is a constant.

Comment: @achillehui without the emphasis , does it implicitly mean  ϵ is a constant  in sentence like "for all ϵ>0,..."?

Comment: @iMath What's after "for all $\epsilon > 0$", is a statement/argument involving the variable $\epsilon$. Within (and only within) the scope of that statement/argument, $\epsilon$ will be a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer to your question is to be found in textbooks on the foundations of mathematics, which explain the meanings of the quantifiers "for all" and "there exists". These quantifiers always have the same meaning in mathematics. Here's a very brief overview (copied from my comments).

Suppose I have a mathematical sentence with a variable $\epsilon$, let's denote that sentence $P(\epsilon)$. The statement "for all $\epsilon>0, P(\epsilon)$" means that $P(.01)$ is true and $P(.0001)$ is true and $P(.00000000001)$ is true and $P(.0000000000409850473265)$ is true, and in fact no matter what positive number I subsitute for $\epsilon$, $P(\epsilon)$ is true. In order to prove that the sentence "for all $\epsilon>0, P(\epsilon)$" is true, I need to give an abstract mathematical argument which starts with the assumption $\epsilon > 0$ and ends with the proof that $P(\epsilon)$ is true.

Now suppose I have a mathematical sentence with a variable $\delta$, let's denote that sentence $Q(\delta)$. The statement "there exists $\delta > 0, Q(\delta)$" means that amongst all the many possible choice of a positive number $\delta$, somewhere there is one value of $\delta$ which makes $Q(\delta)$ true  (there may be more than one, but I don't care, all I need is one). It might not be $\delta = .1$, so I have no guarantee that $Q(.1)$ is true; it might not be $\delta = .0000004987$, so I have no guarnatee that $Q(.0000004987)$ is true; but there is *some* positive value of $\delta$ which makes $Q(\delta)$ true. In order to prove that the sentence "there exists $\delta > 0, Q(\delta)$" is true, I first need to find a particular value of $\delta$, perhaps by solving an equation, or solving an inequality, or digging it out at the bottom of some deep dark mine, or hunting it down in the middle of a deep dark jungle, bring that particular value of $\delta$ out and show it to everybody --- as you can see, this is the fun part of mathematics, especially if you like mining or hunting --- substitute that particular value of $\delta$ into the sentence $Q(\delta)$, and then give a mathematical argument that $Q(\delta)$ is true with that particular $\delta$ substituted.

Now let's put it together and suppose I have a statement $R(\epsilon,\delta)$ which has two variables in it. The statement "for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $R(\epsilon,\delta)$" means that no matter what positive number I substitute for $\epsilon$, somewhere there is a value of $\delta$ which makes $R(\epsilon,\delta)$ true (there may be more than one, but I don't care, all I need is one). In order to prove that the statement "for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $R(\epsilon,\delta)$", I need to give a mathematical argument which starts with the assumption that $\epsilon > 0$, and then I need to find a particular value of $\delta$ which depends on $\epsilon$ --- perhaps given by a particular formula $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ where the right hand side of the formula is a particular functional expression with $\epsilon$'s in it --- and then substitute that formula $\delta(\epsilon)$ into the sentence $R(\epsilon,\delta)$ which converts it into a new sentence having the form $R(\epsilon,\delta(\epsilon))$. Then I must give an abstract mathematical argument which starts with the assumption that $\epsilon>0$, and concludes by verifying that $R(\epsilon,\delta(\epsilon))$ is true.

Comment: As for the statement in your last paragraph  "there exists ϵ>0 such that for all δ>0 , R(ϵ,δ) ", I think it is δ that you could  substitute it with any positive number,not ϵ

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that. The mistake I made was to put the wrong quantifiers in that quote. I've changed the quote.

Comment: Thanks ! As commented here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020171/%CE%B5-is-preassigned-choosen-or-given-in-the-%CE%B5-%CE%B4-definition-of-limit#comment4201056_2020171 ϵ within sentence "for all ϵ>0,..." is implicitly a constant even without the emphasis - preassigned, choosen or given, so no need to have the emphasis. BTW, don't forget to correct the quantifier mistake in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter answer is to reformulate the definition in the following shorter way: there exists a continuous positive strictly increasing function $\alpha(\epsilon)$ satisfying $\alpha(0)=0$ such that whenever the condition $0<|x-c|<\alpha(\epsilon)$ is satisfied, one necessarily has $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$. This lets one get out of the linguistic jungle of "preassigned, chosen or given" altogether.